Print \ref destinations of a \label
Recently, I found in a math book a very useful feature that I would like to implement in LaTeX. The author claimed several propositions and added in the margin, in which other theorems this proposition is referenced (e.g. to prove the theorem). Is there a possibility or a package to do this automatically in LaTeX? This could be something like \label the proposition, \ref it in other theorems, and then use a command to produce the (backward) ref in the proposition to the theorems it is used.


Something like the following should work for you.
Usage Summary
Put and label your theorems in the usual manner: \begin{theorem} \label{th:1}
For propositions, begin the propositions like this: \begin{refproposition}[th:1, th:2], where the entities inside the square brackets are the labels of the theorems this proposition is referring to. This should be comma separated list.
Complete Example
Here is a complete example.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

% For processing the list of references
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\processtheoremreferences}{ m }
{\clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \marginpar[\lbrack\ref{##1}\rbrack]{\lbrack\ref{##1}\rbrack} }}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Propositions with references to theorems
\NewDocumentEnvironment{refproposition}{O{}m}
{\begin{proposition}
    \processtheoremreferences{#1}
#2}{\end{proposition}}

\begin{document}
\section{Contains a Theorem}
\blindtext

\begin{theorem}
  \label{th:1}
  \blindtext
\end{theorem}

\section{There Are Propositions and Theorems}

\blindtext

\bigskip

This proposition does not refer to any theorem.
\begin{refproposition}
  \blindtext
\end{refproposition}

\bigskip
This proposition refers to two theorems.
\begin{refproposition}[th:1, th:2]
  \blindtext
\end{refproposition}

\blindtext

\begin{theorem}
  \label{th:2}
  \blindtext
\end{theorem}

\blindtext

\bigskip
This proposition refers to three theorems.
\begin{refproposition}[th:1, th:2, th:3]
  \blindtext
\end{refproposition}

\begin{theorem}
  \label{th:3}
  \blindtext
\end{theorem}


\end{document}

Outputs
See the outputs.







Thanks a lot, this worked well!

@AlexanderDietz, Glad to be of assistance.
